# Regex match, return remaining rest of string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Simple regex function that matches the start of a string "Bananas: " and returns the second part. I've done the regex, but it's not the way I expected it to work:

```
import re

def return_name(s):
  m = re.match(r"^Bananas:\s?(.*)", s)

  if m:
    # print m.group(0)
    # print m.group(1)
    return m.group(1)

somestring = "Bananas: Gwen Stefani" # Bananas: + name

print return_name(somestring) # Gwen Stefani - correct!
```

However, I'm convinced that you don't have identify the group with `(.*)` in order to get the same results.  ie match first part of string - return the remaining part. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Also I read somewhere that you should be being cautious using `.*` in a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (`(?<=)`):

```
(?<=^Bananas:\s).*
```

Remember to use `re.search` instead of `re.match` as the latter will try to match at the start of the string (aka implicit `^`).

---

As for the `.*` concerns - it can cause a lot of backtracking if you don't have a clear understanding of how regexes work, but in this case it is guaranteed to be a linear search.

Answer (score 1):

Using the alternate regular expression module "[regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)" you could use perl's `\K` meta-character, which makes it able to discard previously matched content and only **K**eep the following.

I'm not really recommending this, I think your solution is good enough, and the lookbehind answer is also probably better than using another module just for that.